# creating a numpy array in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a numpy array by parsing a .txt file. The .txt file consists of features of iris flowers seperated by commas. every line is has one flower example with 5 data seperated with 4 commas. first 4 number is features and the last one is the name. I parse the .txt in a loop and want to append (using numpy.append probably) every lines parsed data into a numpy array called feature_table.

heres the code;

```
import numpy as np
iris_data = open("iris_data.txt", "r")
for line in iris_data:
    currentline = line.split(",")
    #iris_data_parsed = (currentline[0] + " , " + currentline[3] + " , " + currentline[4])
    #sepal_length = numpy.array(currentline[0])
    #petal_width = numpy.array(currentline[3])
    #iris_names = numpy.array(currentline[4])
    feature_table = np.array([currentline[0]],[currentline[3]],[currentline[4]])
    print (feature_table)
    print(feature_table.shape)
```

so I want to create a numpy array using only first, fourth and fifth data in every line
but I can't make it work as I want to. tried reading numpy docs but couldn't understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating numpy arrays in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455008/creating-numpy-arrays-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: You're continously overwriting the same variable, so you get an array with just 3 elements.

Comment: Depending on your ultimate goal, you may be better off using `numpy.loadtxt`, pandas (which has a `read_sv()` function that reads the whole file into a table a.k.a. a Dataframe), or even scikit-learn, which uses the iris data sets in lots of examples.

Comment: @9769953 you are right, but I dont even get an array with 3 elements, I get ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted.

Comment: answer by @Alexander Rossa fixed that. now I just have to create a numpy array outside of the loop and update it every line. thanks

Comment: Collect the line results in a list.  Make the array from the list after the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the people in the comments are right in that you are not persisting your data anywhere, your problem, I assume, is incorrect np.array construction. You should enclose all of the arguments in a list like this:

```
feature_table = np.array([currentline[0],currentline[3],currentline[4]])
```

And get rid of redundant `[` and `]` around the arguments.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) for more examples. Basically all of the input data needs to be grouped/separated to be only 1 argument as Python will consider the other arguemnts as different positional arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. Now I just have to create a numpy array outside of the loop and update it every line.